# How to use the regular expression in mysql query

Tags: mysql, regex

i have following entry in the database:

```
id       summary
1       numbers of word 200 in the doc 0x123
2       [main] numbers of word 150 in the doc 0x678
3       numbers of word 678 in the doc 0x4536 
4       this file has empty
5       not completed
6       numbers of word 86542 in the doc 0x6356
```

I want to retrieve the id from the database "Page" and table name "details" with respect to summary value. i want all the four id (1,2,3,6) with summary value `"numbers of word <any_number> in the doc <any_number>`
And manage with the spaces also...

Answer (score 5):

If you can accept the tradeoff that `%` also matches non-digits, this is trivial using the `LIKE` SQL operator, which is also cross platform.

```
select * from details where lower(summary) LIKE 'numbers of word % in the doc %'
```

If you only want to match digits and spaces, I think you do need regular expressions, which thankfully are directly supported in MySQL. [MySQL 5.1 manual, section 12.5.2: Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). Something like this:

```
select * from details
where lower(summary) REGEXP '^numbers of word [0-9 ]+ in the doc [0-9x ]+$'
```

If you don't need or want case insensitivity you can do away with the call to `LOWER()`. I'm including `x` in the second regular expression because your numbers are prefixed with `0x` (hexadecimal?).

Do keep in mind that indexes likely are not usable with `LIKE` or `REGEXP` which means that the query will incur a comparatively very large I/O cost.